# laravel queue:work are not processing until I run the job synchronously

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-8, laravel-jobs

Laravel version 8.83.17.

I've been using laravel for years and this seems to be a weird problem only occured in one of my mac machine.

Queue driver is using local Redis. have set QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis. And connection is ok.

Then Run `php artisan queue:work --queue=test` on one of the command window

```
class TestJob implements ShouldQueue {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct() {}

    public function handle() {
        Log::debug('TestJobRun');
    }
}
```

Running `TestJob::dispatch()->onQueue('test')` on tinker to dispatch a simple job TestJob. Nothing happend.
until I run `TestJob::dispatchSync()`, suddenly the previous job fired together. with the logs 'TestJobRun'

```
[2023-09-14 19:09:15][a4kFc8yYeVg3agjsFnYP0K5BYbH9NtiD] Processing: App\Jobs\TestJob
[2023-09-14 19:09:15][a4kFc8yYeVg3agjsFnYP0K5BYbH9NtiD] Processed:  App\Jobs\TestJob
```

I just dont know why. how to debug this?

I tried thanging queue, sleep, timeout settings for queue:work. Tried swiching to `queue:listen` or supervisor ways. Nothing helped.

Comment: This is an odd issue to have especially when you're saying it happens on one of your machines, would you consider [Laravel horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon) to inspect your jobs to see if dispatching a job on queue is actually going to queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to the queue you're trying to use. It is related to trying to dispatch a job from tinker.

The `dispatch()` method creates a `PendingDispatch` object instance. The job is sent to the queue from the destructor of the `PendingDispatch` instance, so the job will not be queued until this instance is destroyed.

When running commands in tinker, the result of the last command is kept in memory. Because the result of your last command was the `PendingDispatch` instance, and it is being kept in memory, the destructor is not being called on it, and the job is not dispatching.

The next command you run will push the `PendingDispatch` instance out of memory, call the destructor, and your job will be sent to the queue.

This is why your second call to `TestJob::dispatchSync()` dispatched two jobs. The first one was the one from the `PendingDispatch` instance finally being destroyed, and the second one was the one from the call to `TestJob::dispatchSync()` (which does not use a `PendingDispatch` instance).

In tinker, instead of using the `::dispatch()` method on the job, you can use the `Bus::dispatch()` method directly.

```
Bus::dispatch((new TestJob())->onQueue('test'));
```

Or, you can append another command to your dispatch command so that the result of your command isn't the `PendingDispatch` instance. Ex:

```
TestJob::dispatch()->onQueue('test');echo;
```

Now the result of your command will be the result of the appended `echo;` instead of the `PendingDispatch` instance returned from the `distpatch()`. Therefore, the `PendingDispatch` instance will immediately be destroyed and your job will dispatch.

---

NB: this is also noted in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#usage):

> The `dispatch` helper function and `dispatch` method on the `Dispatchable` class depends on garbage collection to place the job on the queue. Therefore, when using tinker, you should use `Bus::dispatch` or `Queue::push` to dispatch jobs.